# Calculated Column that Doesn't Decrease

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

New here, so cut me some slack if I haven't done this correctly, but I have a problem that has me totally stumped, and I can't find anything else to help.

I'm trying to create a calculated column in Spotfire that will represent the equipment count required for a certain set of circumstances, but that will not go back down over time if those circumstances change in the future.

My data set includes multiple sources, over multiple locations, that have flow rates that vary over time.  These sources come online at various points in time, and the total flow from all sources at each location determines the count of equipment that is needed.  Each source has flow data for each day.  My data set is huge, and has hundreds of locations and sources, over years of data.  I'm trying to forecast equipment needs into the future, and as source rates vary over time, the need for equipment decreases and increases, but the equipment remains when the rates decrease.  I have a calculated column that tells me how much equipment is needed on that given day, by location, but would like a calculated column (vs. a custon expression in a visualization) that goes up as needed, but never goes down, over time.  This way, I can accurately forecast total demand of equipment into the future.

I use DenseRank to rank sources by location and date to create column "Rank", then I use "Ceiling" and "Sum Over Intersect" to create column EquipCount, and then "IF" statement to create a column with a trimmed data set, so it isn't counted multiple times in an aggregated visualization.  "EquipRate" is the flow each piece of equip can handle and is a locally defined property:

```
DenseRank([Source],"ties.method=first",[Location],[Date])

Ceiling(Sum([FlowRate]) over (Intersect([Location],[Date]))/${EquipRate})

if([Rank]=1,[EquipCount],null)
```

Example data set below (continues over multiple sources, locations, and dates):

```
SourceName|Location|Date       |FlowRate

Source 1  |Plant 1 |1/1/2017   |100

Source 1  |Plant 1 |1/2/2017   |200

Source 1  |Plant 1 |1/3/2017   |50

Source 1  |Plant 1 |1/4/2017   |100

Source 2  |Plant 1 |1/8/2017   |100

Source 2  |Plant 1 |1/9/2017   |200

Source 2  |Plant 1 |1/10/2017   |50

Source 2  |Plant 1 |1/11/2017   |100
```

Comment: So what is your question? Did the expressions you used solve your problem?

Comment: The expressions used creates a calculated column for equip. count that is accurate for that date, but does not consider the previous dates.  So, my equip count goes up and down over time.  My question is:  How do I create a calculated column that goes up as needed, but doesn't go back down?

Comment: what would the expected output be for the dataset you provided?